# Set daily limit by comparing time ()

Tags: php, date, limit

I'm creating a script where by inserting comments credits are assigned.
These actions are recorded in a table in the database called "Activity", with the user field (other) and the insertion date of this "posted" action.

I would like to limit the assignment of credits if the counting of the actions on the current day by the user exceeds a TOT.

So if the user has already entered 10 comments today, the credits are no longer placed.
My dilemma is that being the date in time () I can't get the date through.

I am using codeigniter, my little code also using the template is this:

```
$today = mktime (0,0,0, date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
if ($this->default_model->limitCreditiDay($user->id, $today) > 2) {
    echo 'No';
} else {
        echo 'Yes';
}
```

I used mktime thinking to return the date in time through the date () fields, but nothing, the results are always 0 because I will miss something.

The model draws the count of the results where in activity the user and date.
How can I solve it?

EDIT***

```
public function limiteCreditiDay($idUser, $oggi, $domani){
   $this->db->select('id');
   $this->db->from('attivita');
   $this->db->where('idUser', $idUser);
   $this->db->where('posted BETWEEN '.$oggi.' AND '.$domani);
   return $this->db->count_all_results();

}


$oggi = mktime(date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$domani = mktime(date('m'), date('d')+1, date('Y'));
$idUser = 1;
echo $this->default_model->limiteCreditiDay($idUser, $oggi, $domani);
```

But nothing!

Comment: Your problem is unclear - what exactly is not working with your code?

Comment: Sorry for my English, but I used translate. I have to recover how many results are present where the "posted" in time() field is equivalent to the current date (today).

Comment: Please show us what `limitCreditiDay` looks like. Is it expecting a `date` and you're passing through a `timestamp`? Also, try rephrasing your question. It is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: And your DB _column_ `posted `? Is it `date`, `datetime`, or something else?

Comment: The column is a simple varchar where the value of an input time () is entered.

Comment: Please show us an example of what the data looks like. This is important because you're trying to compare a `timestamp` (`mktime `) to it.

Comment: You can think easier, `$this->db->where('date_format(posted, '%Y-%m-%d') = curdate()')` => True for mysql, If you know what database you are using, you should add the tag to get answer easily